# Trigger.io Android mobile app using outdated Facebook SDK? Warning to upgrade to 3.0.1 from Facebook

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, trigger.io, android-facebook

I've recently received an alert in developer.facebook.com for my Android app built using Trigger.io Forge:

> Please upgrade to the Facebook SDK 3.0.1 for Android
>   attentionThursday
>   This app uses an outdated version of the Facebook SDK for Android. Please download the latest version: Android SDK 3.0.1. You can also learn how the newest SDK makes it easier and faster to build great mobile apps.
>
> We also provide an upgrade guide to make this process as easy as possible.
>
> Facebook will stop supporting v2.0 of the SDK in June 2013, so you are advised to upgrade to the new SDK as soon as possible.

I'm using the latest forge platform version 1.4.38.

What version of the FB SDK is Trigger.io using, and what is the schedule for updating to 3.0.1?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! We'll update to the newer SDK as soon as we can - aiming for deployment by the end of next week.

Comment: @james-brady Now that's service :)

Answer (score 0):

We updated our integration to the latest Facebook Android SDK (3.0.1 at this time) in our v1.4.41 platform version:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-41